# jquery mobile popup- server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquerymobile popup like this `<div id="dialogs" data-role="popup">......</div >`
calling this from an anger tag it works fine.. 
how can i show this popup from (ASP.net) server side?

Comment: What do you mean by "from server side"?

Comment: I want to show error message in a popup from server side!!

Comment: your question is bit confusing, from server side means you want to trigger `popup open` from server or you want to load popup html content from server??

Comment: just i want to trigger **popup open** from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send JavaScript code from within ASP.NET like this:

```
void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "popup", "$(document).ready(function() { $('#dialogs').popup(); });", true);

}
```

Having `MyButton_Click` run when a server side button is clicked, it should cause your popup to appear automatically.

Edit: in your specific case, this is the working code:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "popup", "$(document).ready(function() {$.mobile.changePage('#dialogs', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});});", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! this is working for me `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "popup", "$(document).ready(function() {$.mobile.changePage('#dialogs', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});});", true);`

Answer (score 0):

There are different mechisms to achieve this Goal:

- Polling Long
- Polling
- Websocket

You need to use one of them to callback your JavaScript (jquery) from your server. Honestly both of the polling mechanisms are browser -> server one way while long polling makes use of extended timeouts. Only websockets are bidirectional browser <-> server.

Pat

Comment: can you give me some example of this ?

Comment: It's hard to conme up with a solution for you, as I do not now the architecture you are using. 
In general I would recommend using Websocket via:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-websocket/

In addition to that, you need to enable Websockets on the server side. A good overview of Websocket servers can be found here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations